# Code not working with bigger values of for loops

Tags: image, matlab, for-loop, encoding, floating-point

I am implementing a Szudik's pairing function in Matlab, where i pair 2 values coming from 2 different matrices X and Y, into a unique value given by the function '`CantorPairing2D(X,Y)`, After this i reverse the process to check for it's invertibility given by the function '`InverseCantorPairing2( X )`'. But I seem to get an unusual problem, when i check this function for small matrices of size say 10*10, it works fine, but the for my code i have to use a 256 *256 matrices A and B, and then the code goes wrong, actually what it gives is a bit strange, because when i invert the process, the values in the matrix A, are same as cvalues of B in some places, for instance A(1,1)=B(1,1), and A(1,2)=B(1,2). Can somebody help.

```
VRNEW=CantorPairing2D(VRPRO,BLOCK3);

function [ Z ] = CantorPairing2D( X,Y )
[a,~] =(size(X));

Z=zeros(a,a);
for i=1:a
    for j=1:a
        if( X(i,j)~= (max(X(i,j),Y(i,j))) )
            Z(i,j)= X(i,j)+(Y(i,j))^2;
        else
            Z(i,j)= (X(i,j))^2+X(i,j)+Y(i,j);
        end
    end
end
Z=Z./1000;
end

function [ A,B ] = InverseCantorPairing2( X )
[a, ~] =(size(X));
Rfinal=X.*1000;
A=zeros(a,a);
B=zeros(a,a);
for i=1:a
    for j=1:a
        if(  ( Rfinal(i,j)- (floor( sqrt(Rfinal(i,j))))^2) < floor(sqrt(Rfinal(i,j))) )
            T=floor(sqrt(Rfinal(i,j)));
            B(i,j)=T;
            A(i,j)=Rfinal(i,j)-T^2;
        else
            T=floor(    (-1+sqrt(1+4*Rfinal(i,j)))/2      );
            A(i,j)=T;
            B(i,j)=Rfinal(i,j)-T^2-T;
        end
    end
end
end
      Example if     A= 45    16     7    17 
                         7    22    11    25
                        11    12     9    17                       
                         2    11     3     5                        

                      B=   0     0     0     1
                           0     0     0     1
                           1     1     1     1
                           1     3     0     0

          Then after pairing i get 
                      C =2.0700    0.2720    0.0560    0.3070
                         1.4060    0.5060    0.1320    0.6510
                         0.1330    0.1570    0.0910    0.3070
                         0.0070    0.1350    0.0120    0.0300
```

after the inverse pairing i should get the same A and same B. But for bigger matrices it is giving unusual behaviour, because some elements of A are same as B.

Comment: I have edited the code properly, is it readable

Comment: Thank you, that makes a big difference.

Comment: Is it the looping variables , that are causing it to have unusual behaviour?

Comment: Can you please add inputs where you have the expected outputs and at least one set of inputs for which you have a wrong output?

Comment: it has been added

Answer (score 0):

If possible it would help immensely a counter example where your code does fail.

I got to reproduce your code behaviour and I have rewritten your code in a vectorised fashion. You should get the bug, but hopefully it is a first step to uncover the underlying logic and find the bug itself.

I am not familiar with the specific algorithm, but I observe a discrepancy in the CantorPairing definition.

for elements where Y = X your if statement would be false, since X = max(X,X); so for those elements your Z would be X^2+X+Y, but for hypothesis X =Y, therefore your would have: 
X^2+X+X = X^2+2*X;

now, if we perturb slightly the equation and suppose Y = X + 10*eps, your if statement would be true (since Y > X) and your Z would be X + Y ^2; since X ~=Y we can approximate to X + X^2

therefore your equation is very temperamental to numerical approximation ( and you definitely have a discontinuity in Z). Again, I am not familiar with the algorithm and it may very well be the behaviour you want, but it is unlikely: so I am pointing this out.

Following is my version of your code, I report it also because I hope it will be pedagogical in getting you acquainted with logical indexing and vectorized code (which is the idiomatic form for MATLAB, let alone much faster than nested for loops).

```
function [ Z ] = CantorPairing2D( X,Y )
[a,~] =(size(X));

Z=zeros(a,a);

firstConditionIndeces = Y  >  X;  % if  Y > X then X is not the max between Y and X 
% update elements on which to apply first equation 
Z(firstConditionIndeces) = X(firstConditionIndeces) + Y(firstConditionIndeces).^2;

% update elements on the remaining elements
Z(~firstConditionIndeces) = X(~firstConditionIndeces).^2 + X(~firstConditionIndeces) + Y(~firstConditionIndeces) ; 

Z=Z./1000;
end


function [ A,B ] = InverseCantorPairing2( X )
[a, ~] =(size(X));
Rfinal=X.*1000;
A=zeros(a,a);
B=zeros(a,a);
T = zeros(a,a) ; 
% condition deciding which updates to be applied
indecesToWhichApplyFstFcn =  Rfinal- (floor( sqrt(Rfinal )))^2   < floor(sqrt(Rfinal)) ; 

% elements on which to apply the first update
T(indecesToWhichApplyFstFcn) = floor(sqrt(Rfinal )) ; 
B(indecesToWhichApplyFstFcn) = floor(Rfinal(indecesToWhichApplyFstFcn)) ;
A(indecesToWhichApplyFstFcn) = Rfinal(indecesToWhichApplyFstFcn) - T(indecesToWhichApplyFstFcn).^2;

% updates on which to apply the remaining elements
A(~indecesToWhichApplyFstFcn) = floor(    (-1+sqrt(1+4*Rfinal(~indecesToWhichApplyFstFcn  )))/2      ) ; 
B(~indecesToWhichApplyFstFcn) = Rfinal(~indecesToWhichApplyFstFcn) - T(~indecesToWhichApplyFstFcn).^2 - T(~indecesToWhichApplyFstFcn) ; 

end
```